# Angular2 Pipe, Checkbox default false. Angular reads True

Tags: html, angular, pipe

Trying to run a pipe that filters data based on criteria if a checkbox is true. This pipe works great but only after I click the box to True then back to False then true again.

In this case, I have people I want to filter if they have a status. It should show everyone regardless of their status. When the application loads, its as if the filter is turned on and we see only those with a status. If I turn the checkbox on and then off, only then does it show everyone.

Its like Angular reads the checkbox as True at launch even though the DOM is showing it as false. What am I missing?

## Pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';


@Pipe({
    name: 'filterBOD'
})

export class FilterBOD implements PipeTransform {

        transform(members: any, BOD: boolean): any {
            // check if search term is undefined
            if (BOD === false) return members;
            // return update name array
            return members.filter(function(member){
                return member.Board.toLowerCase().includes('Board of Director -'.toLowerCase());
            })

    }

}
```

## DOM

```
<div class="nameSearchContainer">
                <div class="namesearchlabel">Search Member Name:</div>
                <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="term" />
                <span class="fa fa-search"></span>
            </div>

            <!-- Board of Directos Toggle -->
            <div class="BODContainer">
                <label for="boardtoggle">Show Board Of Directors Only:</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="boardtoggle" checked="false" [(ngModel)]="BOD"/>
            </div>

            <hr>

            <!-- Cards -->

            <div class="cardwrapper" *ngFor="let member of members | filterBOD:BOD | filterName:term   ">
                <div class="cardTitle"> {{ member.Board }} {{ member.Title }} </div>
                <div class="cardContainer">
                    <div class="idContainer">
                        <h1>ID</h1>
                        <h2>{{ member.ID }}</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="nameContainer">
                        <h1>{{ member.FirstName }} {{ member.LastName }} </h1>
                        <span class="fa fa-user" *ngIf="member.Membership === 'Regular'" > {{ member.Membership }} </span>
                        <span class="fa fa-users" *ngIf="member.Membership === 'Family'" > {{ member.Membership }} </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="contactInfo">
                        <div class="addressContainer">
                            <span class="fa fa-envelope"></span>
                            <div class="address">
                                <p> {{ member.Address}} </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="phoneContainer">
                            <span class="fa fa-phone"></span>
                            <div class="phone">
                                <p> {{ member.Phone }}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="emailContainer">
                            <span class="fa fa-at"></span>
                            <div class="email">
                                <p> {{ member.Email }}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="contactvia">
                        <img src="./components/images/seperator.png" class="verticledivider">
                        <h1>Contact VIA</h1>
                        <h2>{{ member.ContactPref }} </h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `BOD` is initially equal to `undefined`, so it fails your `BOD === false` ("BOD is a boolean and equal to false") check.

Just use `if (!BOD) return members;` instead to have it work for `false` and `undefined`.